# how to reference a view in android without need for inflating

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I keep getting an error that says cannot resolve method findViewById . I understand that this is probably because findViewById method works with a specific view or its  descendants . I would like to check a radio button in another view whilst I am in another view. How do I then reference that view without having to inflate . This is the line of code that is giving me the "cannot resolve method findViewById" error . This radio button is actually in another view.

```
  RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb_data_all);
     r1.checked(true);
```

Comment: where is the code you posted located?

Comment: Somehow, in your code, you need to get the layout's view reference and use the findViewById on that view. E.g view.findViewById(R.id.rb_data_all);

Answer (score 0):

You said:-

> "cannot resolve method findViewById "

That means it is undefined , and I assume you want the one from Activity Class so 
try this.

1) Extend your activity class to `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`

2) Override `onCreate(Bundle instance)` at least and it should work.